# Child container controller not receiving viewWillLayoutSubviews after Rotation event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller that's a child of a container controller and I'd like to know how to handle resizing the views when the orientation changes on the device. **The child controller isn't receiving the expected viewWillLayoutSubviews event.**

I'm under the impression that 'viewWillLayoutSubviews' is called when the bounds of the view change but the bounds value remains the same between ChildViewController's willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation events.  **Why is that?**

The view specific events I'm seeing during rotation are:

```
[ParentViewController viewDidLoad]
[ParentViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
[ParentViewController layoutHomeForStartup]
[ParentViewController viewDidAppear:]
[ParentViewController showLoginView]

[ChildViewController viewDidLoad]
[ChildViewController didMoveToParentViewController:]

[ParentViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]

[ChildViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
[ChildViewController viewDidAppear:]
[ChildViewController showLoginPanel]

[ParentViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:]
[ChildViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:]

[ParentViewController viewWillLayoutSubviews]
// QUESTION: Why doesn't the childViewController not receive viewWillLayoutSubviews?

[ParentViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:]
[ChildViewController didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:]
```

Here's how I'm adding the child controller to the parent:

```
// ParentViewController:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ChildViewController *childViewController = [ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName...];

    [childController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:childController];
    [view addSubview:childController.view];
    [childController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

Because I'm still targeting iOS 5.0+ devices, I also have implemented:

```
- (BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers 
{
    return YES;
}
```

`shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` and `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` are also implemented and return YES (for those using iOS 6+);

I'm not sure what the best way to handle orientation changes within the container controler's child view controller.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1.

`automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers` is actually two methods:

they are called `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` and `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods`

**even if it was 1 method under IOS5, you have to implement the newer variants too for IOS6**

#### 2.

the bounds of the children dont seem to change you said in the comments and this makes sense. So call `setNeedsLayout` on the view controllers' views to make them layout themselves :)

Comment: They became 2 methods in iOS6 and since I'm still starting devices that run iOS 5, they are not available to me.

Comment: Ah sorry. But you need to implement those TOO. Same as with the houldRotate stuff. Ill edit my answer to be more explicit.

Comment: I think the problem is that the child view's bounds aren't changing. My understanding is that when the bounds change, viewWillLayoutSubviews is invoked.

Comment: well, that might be true as well.. they aren't rotated... call setNeedsLayout on the view to force it to layout its subviews

Comment: So call setNeedsLayout in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation or from parent viewController's viewWillLayoutSubviews, call the child's setNeedsLayout?